# Como salvar dados JSON no disco rígido? (ou acessa-los com javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, lado-do-cliente

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação para estudar a sintaxe de linguagens usadas na web (html, css, javascript e etc...), através de um "minijogo" de perguntas e respostas, mas meu problema tem sido como salvar esses dados.

O método que eu aprendi é esse abaixo:

```
/* coloque os dados em um array */

var dados = ["mizuk","programação","animes"];

/* guarde os dados recebidos no navegador */

localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(dados));

/* passe os dados para um novo array */

var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

/* imprima no console os dados recebidos */

console.log(" nome: " + user[0] + "\n trabalha com: " 
   + user[1] + "\n e gosta de: " + user[2]);
```

O problema disso é que dessa forma os dados ficam salvos somente no navegador e se eu quisesse levar essa aplicação para outro lugar (meu celular por exemplo), eu não conseguiria.

Alguém conhece uma forma de salvar esses dados localmente ou simplesmente acessa-los no "servidor" através de javascript? (de forma que eu possa colocar as perguntas como arquivos JSON em uma pasta, e depois acessar com javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte função:

```js
var dados = ["mizuk","programação","animes"];

function baixarArquivo(name) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,' + JSON.stringify(dados);
    link.download = name;
    link.click();
}
```

```html
<a onclick="baixarArquivo('arquivo.json')">Download</a>
```

Essa função vai:

- criar um link
- definir o endereço como sendo o arquivo que você quer
  salvar
- definir um nome para o arquivo a ser salvo
- clicar automaticamente no link

Dessa forma o arquivo é salvo automaticamente